# Memcached not working in php

Tags: php, linux, memcached

I can't make memcache work. I followed [this tutorial](http://www.howtoforge.com/install-memcached-and-php5-memcached-module-on-debian-6.0-squeeze) and when I try the example from the last part of the tutorial I don't get any output.

Here's the code from the tutorial.

```
$m = new Memcached();
$m->addServer('localhost', 11211);
$m->set('key', 'hello world');
var_dump($m->get('key'));
```

When I load it to my webpage I don't get any output. It says error. What's wrong with my server? I installed it correctly and checked my phpinfo and found it there. why can't I make it work?

**UPDATE:**

I'm using virtualbox.. and debian is my guest os. and everything is working in php it's just that i can't make it work for memcached

Comment: What is the error you receive?

Comment: You need both the PHP module and the Memcached server. Did you install both?

Comment: in firefox it only blank page.. in google chrome it says error in server.

Comment: @staticsan yes i do have php module and memcached. i followed the tutorial.

Answer (score 4):

Start memcached daemon in the terminal like so:

```
memcached -vv -m64 -l127.0.0.1
```

Comment: i got it working now.. just problem with my server.. thanks for all the help

Comment: @demic0de runs memcached in the foreground with 64MB of memory and -vv means to be verbose during the event loop; print out errors and warnings.

Comment: Interesting to know, that PHP does not launch the memached by itself.

Comment: When you install php-memcached on Ubuntu, note that it doesn't install memcached itself. You have to do `apt-get install memcached php-memcached` to get both. When you do that, the latest Ubuntu packages will automatically add the memcached service so that you don't have to launch the daemon on reboot or after installation.